# All matching square brackets under cursor are highlighted

Tags: c++, visual-studio

[image]

How to enable single match under cursor?
For curly brackets and round brackets single pair is highlighted.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the font background color in Visual Studio 2022's tool -> options.
[image]
[image]

In addition, Visual Studio enables single match by default(Click once on brace).

Maybe you changed settings, try resetting options.

`Tools -> Import and Export settings -> Reset all settings.`